# How can I inspect element in to div with jsname?

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, bdd, cucumber-java

I'm having trouble inspecting elements inside a DIV; I don't want to use xpath.

```
     // Assert.assertEquals("Digite uma senha",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"view_container\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span")).getText()); 
     // System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"view_container\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span")).getText()); 
             //  driver.close();
```

}[image]

Comment: Are you trying to access the span in side the highlighted div?

Comment: forgive me i need to get the text: "Digite uma senha".

Comment: Try with `div[jsname='B34EJ'] span` css selection.

Comment: Perfect "You are the best!!!" Thank u X 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below css.

```
div[jsname='B34EJ'] span
```

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left hand side in my answer.

Comment: Please, Do you have a query source where there are several examples for using DIV? Thank u

Comment: you can check CSS Selector reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)