# Selenium find a element with no class, div, text (Python)

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver

I want to make a automatic google login with selenium but i cannot find the elements, the butto[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l987x.png)n "Next", because the class
is modified each time when we come to start a browser with selenium, or when we reset the login page and does not have Id, but the button is in a div that includes just this button,
I would like someone to help me find a solution to find how I can use this button in order to click it to skip the page where you have to put your email address to skip to the password

i would like to use css selector

(Google Chrome the browser I use)
I code with Selenium 4.2.0 on Linux Unbuntu

Comment: Please post the code or error as text in your question, not an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc LQeN7 qIypjc TrZEUc lw1w4b"]').click()
```

That will click the 'Next' button on Google login. Good luck getting any further though. Google seems to block logging in on Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use jsname as an alternative for finding the element
I found a similar question here [How can I inspect element in to div with jsname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427704/how-can-i-inspect-element-in-to-div-with-jsname)
I think the person is doing pretty same thing
Hope this helps :)